# Ballerina: mysterious "method is too large" error

Tags: ballerina

I'm trying to convert a Ballerina 0.991.0 project to 1.1.0. When running `ballerina build -a`...

```
Compiling source
        domain/mymodule:0.0.1
        domain/main:0.0.1

Creating balos
        target/balo/mymodule-2019r3-any-0.0.1.balo
        target/balo/main-2019r3-any-0.0.1.balo
error: domain:myproject:mymodule:1:1: method is too large: 'bidalaka/mymodule:0.0.1.<init>'
error: error: domain:myproject:mymodule:1:1: method is too large: 'bidalaka/mymodule:0.0.1.<init>'
```

I have no idea what this `<init>` method is because it's nothing I've defined. I can't find any documentation about it. What does this really mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: The <init> method is a compiler-generated method. We do that for each and every module in your project. This method performs module initialization. Refer to https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/2019R3/#section_8.2 for more information.

What do you have as module-level variables in your module 'mymodule'?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have a bunch of public const and final variables available at the module level. Is there anything specific you're looking for?

Comment: @SameeraJayasoma is there any work around to this? I am constructing a XML and it quite a long one, and I am encountering " method is too large:", is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Mayuran if you are not doing any xml interpolations then just write the xml literal as a string and use fromString method in lang-lib https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/api-docs/ballerina/lang.xml/functions.html#fromString

Comment: @Dhananjaya Thanks for the suggestion, But I am really using some function call to dynamically build XML, I have managed to split the method into 2 separate function and made it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue in Ballerina at the moment. What you can do as a workaround is to extract some of those consts into separate module.